# FragmentStatePageAdapter: Multiple Items visible at the same time - How to center a specific page?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'd like to use a `FragmentStatePageAdapter` and display 3 items at the same time.
This could be done by overriding the `getPageWidth()`-Method:

```
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 0.33f;
    }
```

This works great. But my problem is that I'd now like to have the centered page in focus. Currently the left page is in focus...

I've visualized the problem:

Currently:[image: Current Pager]

Desired: [image: Desired Pager]

Desired 2 (If you scroll until the end): [image: Desired Page 2]

What would you suggest?

Comment: In terms of the focus, set the focus on the desired widget yourself. In terms of your bottom figure, that is not possible AFAIK, unless you have an `INVISIBLE` page 0.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It's not just the focus. The current page is "highlighted" - a bit in the foreground and has another color

Comment: I am not aware that `ViewPager` highlights pages. Hence, AFAIK, the highlight effect is something that you are doing.

Comment: maybe it's the fragmentstatepageadapter? the current page is a bit bigger and the other pages have some alpha value

Comment: sorry my fault, it's a zoom-out-page-transformer

Comment: Ah, I have not tried `PageTransformer` with `getPageWidth()`. I am not terribly surprised that there is a conflict there. I have no idea how to address that, sorry.

Comment: no sorry, i wanted to mention that i'm indeed using a transformer... I can now handle my problem I guess ;) Thanks to you!

Comment: If you answer my question I can accept it. because now I got everything i need. I don't transform the page and I'm using a fake page 0 to get my second case ;)

Comment: I was the same problem... Can you share you code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recapping the comment thread:

- The issue regarding "focus" was due to the application of a `PageTransformer`. `PageTransformer` appears to be oblivious to `getPageWidth()` and will transform only the first visible page.
- To center the "first" page, you will need an invisible page before that one. `ViewPager` always starts from the left, so the default would be to put the first page on the left. Having an invisible first page would put the first *visible* page in the next slot over. Note that depending on what behavior is desired for the end of the roster of pages, you may need one or more invisible pages there too.